# Are there pencil extenders for charcoal pencils?

Tags: pencils, charcoal, tool-modification

I bought a pencil extender. It works great for graphite pencils, which are thinner. However, charcoal pencils are too thick for it. How can I use my charcoal pencils when they are too short to hold?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume you're talking about Conté pencils (Fusain Charcoal, which often come in sets with grey and white Conté).

Caran d'Ache has a pencil extender with a 9 mm diameter, which should be sufficient for those pencils, which are slightly smaller.
You can search for 'FixPencil 0012' or 'CARAN 12.009' (e.g. [here](https://www.alwaysfashion.com/en/caran-dache-pencil-holder-12009)).

And there are generic brand double-ended pencil extenders that allow up to 10 mm [here](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B07SZDB7B9).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But I meant that charcoal pencils are too 'fat'. There is no way they can fit. Do you know about pencil holders for 'fatter' pencils?

Comment: Thanks, @Curiousmind, I skimmed your question apparently. I updated my answer: is this helpful?

Comment: That's just perfect. Thank you very much!